# format currency in specific way for only one culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, culture

I am working on a multi lingual application that shows product prices in different currencies. I use the .net library to format currencies based upon culture eg.

```
CultureInfo current = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        return value.Value.ToString("C", current);
```

A Russian client is not happy with how this displays so for example they want 100 руб. showing and not 100,00 р as at the moment.

Is there an easy way to modify how the price string is generated without affecting other conversions to their culture currency?

Comment: What do you mean by "other conversions"? Conversions in the same culture elsewhere in your code, or conversions in other cultures?

Comment: conversions in other cultures

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom price format for some cultures.
For example: If you have Culture table in your db. You should add *CustomPriceFormat* column with default value "{0:C}". In this case your can change some price formats of cultures.
Then you can use like this:

```
var priceString = string.Format(currentCulture.CustomPriceFormat, d);
```

For Russian culture *CustomPriceFormat* is "{0:N} руб".